# Get val() of dynamically created input field

Tags: jquery

I've got the following code:

```
$('document').ready(function() {

    $('#container').append('<input type="text" id="mystuff"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:showStuff();">Show stuff</a>');
});

function showStuff() {

    alert($('#mystuff').val());
}
```

Problem is the alert says `undefined`, probably because the element `mystuff` is dynamically created. I've had similar problems with dynamically created elements before. In those cases I could use `.on()` but in this case I don't think I can, because I just want to store the val() to a variable. There's no event I want to bind to `mystuff`...

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Works for me. http://jsfiddle.net/vJYnd/

Comment: Try `alert($('#mystuff'))`. If it works, then `val` is the problem

Comment: What value are you expecting `$('#mystuff').val()` to return?

Comment: I don't see a problem with this code. Are you getting this error in a specific browser?

Comment: What the hell. Ok, yeah, then there's some other problem in my code, probably some typo or whatever. Thanks though

Comment: @CarlCarlsson Is all of the code above wrapped in a `.load` or `.ready` handler by any chance?

Comment: @Asad No, because if it were then the alert wouldn't be undefined, it simply wouldn't happen. :)

Comment: @KevinB True. Not sure what else it could be.

Answer (score 1):

There are already good answers here, so I will show you how to create the same affect in Pure JavaScript!  This will definitely speed up the loading time for your website if you are only using JQuery for something as simple as this!

```
document.addEventListener('load', function() {

    function showStuff() {
        alert(document.querySelector('#mystuff').value);
    }

    document.querySelector('#container').innerHTML += `
        <input type='text' id='mystuff'>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:showStuff();">Show stuff</a
    `;

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to have the pleasure of using JQuery, get rid of all that awful inline Javascript.

```
$('document').ready(function() {

    $('#container').append('<input type="text" id="mystuff" /><a id="show_stuff" href="#">Show stuff</a>');
    $("#show_stuff").click(showStuff);
});

function showStuff() {

    alert($('#mystuff').val());
}
```

Much cleaner!

Comment: Unobtrusive code even applies to code you generate.  This is a good example of that.

Comment: @SurrealDreams Ummm what?

Comment: If what he currently has is alerting undefined, it's a safe bet this will still alert undefined. Most likely the real problem is non-unique id's.

Comment: Inline JavaScript like onclick events written into HTML is sometimes referred to as obtrusive.  It's ugly, hard to maintain, and can easily violate the DRY principle - don't repeat yourself.  Unobtrusive code (like you wrote) removes the script from the HTML and places it with the rest of the script code.  It's a good thing.

Comment: @Asad Well its impossible to know what's causing the OP's problem as the snippet he has looks fine. I don't think this is considered a stylistic "preference", I think this is best practice. How would I have possibly put this in a comment anyway? I need the code formatting.

Comment: @thatidiotguy If that is the case you should wait for clarification instead of posting an answer that simply refactors the code. You can put it in a comment like so: "You should separate the event handler from your markup by attaching it using jQuery: `$("#show_stuff").click(showStuff);`". That's really the only thing you added, besides removing the event handler.

Comment: There is no click event,  how do you do this without click event.

Comment: @NotoriousPet0 There is a click event handler. I don't know what you are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

The below works in chrome:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('document').ready(function() {

    $('#container').append('<input type="text" id="mystuff"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:showStuff();">Show stuff</a>');
});

function showStuff() {

    alert($('#mystuff').val());
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Typically though, I would use $(document) without quotes.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is you have not defined value attribute for the container.
by this code:

```
$('#container').append('<input type="text" id="mystuff" value="info"><a   
href="javascript:void(0);"      
onclick="javascript:showStuff();">Show stuff</a>');
```

you will get the value.

alert(document.getElementById("container").innerHTML);

will return whatever inside of #container.
tested!

Comment: It doesn't work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/YYcXZ/8/ input elements don't have innerHTML.

Comment: I just changed my answer

Answer (score 0):

you could trigger event also directly on the a tag just like this.

```
$('document').ready(function() {
     $('#container').append('<input type="text" id="mystuff">',
        $('<a href="">Show stuff</a>').click(function() {
            alert($('#mystuff').val())
        })
    )
});
```

Look's good and easy to read!