# How do I execute some code after an element has been created in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically I want to do something like this:

```
$("#myElement").ready(function(){
    $("#myElement").attr("id", "new-id");
});
```

Is this possible? I've looked at jQuery `live()` which is now deprecated and instead they recommend to use `on()`, but all solutions I've seen requires event handlers to be attached to the element, such as click, hover etc. I don't want to attach event handlers, **I want to simply modify the HTML that is loaded, when it's loaded in the future.**

The HTML is loaded by ajax and in this particular case I have no access to modify the ajax file.

Comment: could you show your ajax function that create the elements?

Comment: ready pseudo event must be bound only to document. Here, ready event is fired once DOM is ready, nothing about element "#myElement" added or not in DOM

Comment: @daguru Sorry. It's a long and complicated function that would add more confusion that clarity in this case. But basically it "just" adds the html into a container, based on some settings.

Comment: If you look at the duplicate question I proposed: The accepted answer, in the **update** part, seems to be what you are looking for

Comment: PS: sorry, didn't saw that: ` I have no access to modify the ajax file.`  You could use ajax global method for that

Comment: Look at this, but you necessarily have to use event handlers: [Link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18254257/get-val-of-dynamically-created-input-field/18254670#18254670

Comment: @musefan Thank you, on DOMNodeInserted event worked flawlessly. Precisely what I was after. But I can mark a comment as answered. Write a short answer about it and I'll mark yours as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**MutationObserver**

Using [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) is the currently recommended method, although browser support requires **IE11+**:

```
var target = document.getElementById('content');

var observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function (mutation) {
        for (var i = 0; i < mutation.addedNodes.length; i++) {
            var addedNode = mutation.addedNodes[i];
            if (addedNode.id == "myElement") {
                alert("#myElement added!");
            }
        }
    });
});

var config = {
    attributes: true,
    childList: true,
    characterData: true
};
observer.observe(target, config);
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/BKm3J/)

---

**Mutation Events (deprecated)**

This method is deprecated, but will offer browser support from **IE9+**:

> This feature has been removed from the Web. Though some browsers may
>   still support it, it is in the process of being dropped. Do not use it
>   in old or new projects. Pages or Web apps using it may break at any
>   time.

([Above extract taken from here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events))

With Mutation Events there is an event called `DOMNodeInserted` which you can listen out for, you can also specify the `#myElement` selector to get the exact element(s) you want.

This example uses JQuery:

```
$(document).on('DOMNodeInserted', '#myElement', function(){
    $("#myElement").attr("id", "new-id");
});
```

NOTE: `document` should be replaced with what ever selector you need, the more you can limit the area the better.

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/2Tq9B/) (element added after 2 seconds)

Comment: using this event on document level could really be a performance killer, but that's depend of OP site of course

Comment: As @toutpt already pointed out towards Nunners, Mutation Events are deprecated. [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) should be used instead – though I would prefer [Watch.js](https://github.com/melanke/Watch.JS?utm_source=javascriptweekly)

Comment: @A.Kalkhoff as i'm aware of, watch.js is for javascript object, not DOM node

Comment: @A.Wolff: I didn't have anything else to work with, but yes the more specific the better

Comment: @musefan ya true, but, at least, this should be specified i think. EDIT: ok, i see your EDIT ;) +1 even i'd personally never use this kind of event

Comment: @A.Wolff ah, true. Has been a while since I last used it – I had in mind that it was possible to watch a property of an element and thus achieving the wanted effect, my bad there :/

Comment: @A.Kalkhoff this is still a great plugin imo ;)

Comment: @A.Kalkhoff: It seems browser support is more restricted for  MutationObserver, but I will add something about it to my answer!

Comment: @musefan You should at least mention the state of deprecation and thus possibly future risks

Comment: @A.Kalkhoff: yep, done that now. phew, that was hard work

Comment: @musefan Well deserved upvote there ;) Good work!

Answer (score 1):

Using global ajax:

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function (event, xhr, settings) {
   if(settings.url === "urlOfSpecificAjax" && $("#myElement").length)
      $("#myElement").attr("id", "new-id");
});
```

This supposes the ajax request is done using jQuery and global option not set to false (true is default)

Answer (score 0):

you need to use a delegated selector. It would look at the static parent element (that is in the DOM) and then find something inside of it by the id you want.

```
$('.parent-in-DOM').on('click', '#thing-not-in-DOM',function(){
var id = $(this).attr('id');//$(this) is it
    alert("i found "+id);
});
```

check out jquery .on()

Comment: Correct me if I'm not understanding this correctly: Wouldn't this only work if the '.parent-in-DOM' is clicked? It does detect whether the element has been created or not, but it does not fire at the moment it is created (which is the goal)

Answer (score -1):

There are no events emited when dom is modified, so you can't bind on an event.

You are loading content with ajax and you want it to be modified by javascript, so you have to plug into the ajax callback

You must write a transform function that will be called by your ajax callback:

```
var transformid = function(){
   $("#myElement").attr("id", "new-id");
}

$.ajax({
  url: "your.php",
}).done(function() {
  transformid();
});
```

Comment: This is incorrect, the DOMNodeInserted event can be used which jQuery to monitor the container. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events

Comment: Werblurk said : "`I have no access to modify the ajax file.`"

Comment: it is deprecated @Nunners

Comment: @daguru "ajax file" doesn't make sens I have understood "I can't modify the ajax response ....